# on click change background image with fade jquery

Tags: jquery, background, transition, fade, effect

I would like to change the background of header when i click on swipe2 but i also want to change it with some fade efect, cand someone help me ? this is the code:

```js
$('#swipe2').click(function() {
  if($('#title2').css('display') == 'none')
  {
   $('#title1').hide();
   $('#title2').fadeIn(1000);
   $("#a-plus").fadeOut(200);
   $("#a-plus").fadeIn(500);
  
  $("header").css('backgroundImage','url(images/banner2.jpg)');
  }

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try customizing with the help of [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadein)

Comment: Running your snippet returns an empty result... Include some HTML